# Map on image in flutter (like in html)

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I'm working on an app where I need map-like in html function.. the thing is I have the website ready

- The website shows a picture of an auto-part with multiple clickable areas so the user can select which
  part to select
  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEKO.png)
  I wondering if I can find this functionality in Flutter
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, can you share some code? What have you tried? Where does your code fail?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this package yet but this might work for you - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_map

From what I've seen in the readme/example tab you should be able to achieve your design.